# Display id attribute of closest section tag to scrollbar in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to display the id of the section tag that's closest to the scrollbar position.

I'm assuming from what I've been reading I'm approaching this the wrong way.

I've tried a number of variants similar to the one below without any luck.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    $('.nameplate').text("$(event.target).find("section").attr('id')"); 
});
```

I'm trying to achieve what's shown in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LDEtu/). I want the

tags at bottom to display the ids of section tag closest to the scrollbar, in this case "three" (C).

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know at some point I didn't and i still got undefined in the console log.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(event) {
    $('.nameplate').text($(event.target).find("section").attr('id')); 
});
```

You had quotes around `$(event.target)` and also missing `event` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks. That fixes the technical issues with the code itself, but I'm still not getting the text of the id attribute of the nearest section tag. So I'm assuming the approach needs to be altered?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code that this jQuery is referring to, or perhaps make a fiddle? Very hard to fix without related codes